# How make luabind work in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, lua, luabind

I've been trying the [hello world](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#hello-world) example of Luabind in Ubuntu, but I cannot make it work. Would anyone know how to make this example work in Ubuntu using g++?

```
kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ cat hellobind.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <luabind/luabind.hpp>

void greet()
{
    std::cout << "hello world!\n";
}

extern "C" int init(lua_State* L)
{
    using namespace luabind;

    open(L);

    module(L)
    [
        def("greet", &greet)
    ];

    return 0;
}
kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ g++ hellobind.cpp -I/usr/include/lua5.2/ -c -fPIC
kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ g++ -shared -Wl,--whole-archive -o hellobind.so hellobind.o -lluabind -Wl,--no-whole-archive
kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ cat test.lua 
require 'hellobind'
greet()
kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ lua test.lua 
lua: error loading module 'hellobind' from file './hellobind.so':
    ./hellobind.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_hellobind
stack traceback:
    [C]: in ?
    [C]: in function 'require'
    test.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$
```

When I run the lua script, lua complains "undefined symbol: luaopen_hellobind".

My system details are as follows:

```
kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | egrep 'lua|boost'
libboost-date-time1.54.0:amd64          install
libboost-dev                    install
libboost-system1.54.0:amd64         install
libboost1.54-dev                install
libboost1.55-tools-dev              install
liblua5.2-0:amd64               install
liblua5.2-dev:amd64             install
libluabind-dev                  install
libluabind-examples             install
libluabind0.9.1                 install
lua5.2                      install
kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ uname -a
Linux castor-ub 3.19.0-43-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 15:44:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at this example [here](https://github.com/luabind/luabind/tree/master/examples/hello_world), and they seem to load the shared library differently. Try a lua script like this:

```
package.loadlib('hellobind.so', 'init')()
greet()
```

Comment: Zekian, I tried your suggestion and I get this error:

    kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ cat test.lua 
    loadlib('hellobind.so', 'init')()
    greet()
    kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ lua test.lua 
    lua: test.lua:4: attempt to call global 'loadlib' (a nil value)
    stack traceback:
     test.lua:4: in main chunk
     [C]: in ?

Comment: Ah it seems that in newer versions of lua, it is package.loadlib

Comment: hi Zekian, unfortunately, it still does not work. thank you very much for helping though.
    `kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ cat test.lua 
    package.loadlib('hellobind.so', 'init')()
    greet()
    kuyu@castor-ub:~/dkuyu/Dropbox/practice/lua/luabind$ lua test.lua 
    lua: test.lua:1: attempt to call a nil value
    stack traceback:
     test.lua:1: in main chunk
     [C]: in ?`

Comment: I compiled the lib on my computer with g++ 5.4, it worked fine. Perhaps your lib does not have an entry for `init` but rather something like `_init`. You can see the library's symbols with `nm -D hellobind.so`, check whether it contains `init`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the tips, @Zekian. i was finally able to make it work by using `package.loadlib('./hellobind.so', 'init')()`. the `./` is important, as apparently, loadlib couldn't find the file hellobind.so. The following code also helped me in figuring out what was not working: `local initfunction, errormessage = package.loadlib('hellobind.so','init')
if errormessage then
    print('Error loading hellobind:', errormessage)
end`